# enviar variables de sesión de una aplicación a otra

Tags: php, session, yii2

```html
        $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet', ['title' => 'GXD', 'contentCssClass' => 'portlet-content-menu']);
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', [
            'items'            => [
                [
                    'label'  => Yii::t('gxdMsgs', 'peopleManagement'),
                    'url'    => Yii::app()->params['httpNormalScheme']."://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=site",
                     
         
                ],
                [
                    'label' => Yii::t('gxdMsgs', 'performanceManagement'),
                    'url'    => Yii::app()->params['httpNormalScheme']."://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=site",
                ],
              
            ],
            'htmlOptions'      => ['class' => 'ctv-menu'],
            'linkLabelWrapper' => 'span',
            'encodeLabel'      => false,
        ]);
        $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet');
```

estoy trabajando con una aplicación en yii2 cuyo acceso (autenticación de usuario) se hace desde otra aplicación ya existente en yii1.1, mi problema es cómo enviar las variables de session ya existentes en la aplicación hecha en yii1.1 a la que estoy desarrollando en yii2? Me pueden orientar con esto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: las dos aplicaciones que mencionas comparten la misma sesión o se ejecutan en entornos diferentes?

Comment: no soy un experto en yi; pero creo que lo conveniente seria enviar las variables del usuario por POST con la que se hace el loggin y que se inicie la sesión en ambos lugares... independientemente del entorno... si quieres hablas sobre métodos de seguridad para proteger esa sesión seria un tema muy amplio y de discusión ... tal vez en el chat tenga una mejor recepción; en cuanto a este post se necesita un ejemplo del código que tienes realizado un ejemplo y que digas donde o que error tienes...

Comment: @Claudio  cada aplicación tiene una ip distinta, por lo que entiendo almacenadas en aws una en yii1.1 que es la que proporciona las varibles de session y la otra en yii2 que las recibe.  Intenté hacerlo con localStorage y no pasa las variables de "un dominio a otro"

Comment: Lo que indica @FranciscoNúñez es correcto. Si envías la variable por POST seria saludable y seguro.

Comment: @Claudio cómo envío la variable por post?? he intentado hacerlo de mil maneras y nada me funciona.  Agrego el código del menú como está en la app de yii1.1 con las opciones que deben redirigir a mi aplicación en yii2

Comment: @Francisco Núñez cómo se hace eso??? Lo he intentado de mil formas y nada me ha funcionado. Hasta incluyendo un form y metiendo el menú dentro de ese form con method post pero no se redirige a donde quiero, se queda en la misma vista

Comment: deberías seguir estos pasos:

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/48165

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27212562/4717133

Comment: tu pregunta tiene más relacion con temas de seguridad ... por que el *como se hace* es un off-topic de este sitio

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @Francisco Núñez

Comment: COnceptualmente hablando porque lamentablemente no manejo Yii2 como frame. Una variable POST se envia cargando un formulario con el metodo POST. Luego, dentro del formulario (entre los tags FORM y /FORM) debes declarar una variable hidden con el valor que quieras compartir. Por ejemplo <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $variable;?>" readonly="" />. Si reemplazas $variable por $:SESSIONXX tendras lo que buscas.